# Polymer How to pass returned iron-ajax string into another polymer element

Tags: ajax, polymer

So i'm currently able to grab iron-ajax data and load it into my element fine but where i have come across some issues is that i have another custom element inside my parent element which takes in a 'workerid'.

Problem is that the 'workerid' actually becomes back from the iron-ajax call, so i handle the response with handleResponse, but by this time, it has already attached the nested element with 'null' for the worker id.

I'm  not sure how i can solve this problem. Heres my code.

The parent element takes in a var 'bookingid' as documented

```
<template>

        <!-- Ajax call to retrieve the data -->
        <iron-ajax
            id="ajax"
            method="GET"
            url="../api/bookings/"
            params='{{params}}'
            handle-as="json"
            on-response="handleResponse"
            last-response="{{data}}">
        </iron-ajax>

        <div class="single-booking">

            <div class="assigned-worker-container">
                <user-display userid="{{data.workerid}}"></user-display> 
            </div>

        </div>

</template>


        <script>

        Polymer({
                    is: "job-booking",

                    properties: {
                        data: {
                            type: Object,
                            notify: true
                        },
                        bookingid: String
                    },

                    ready: function(){  

                        // Set parameters   
                        this.params = { 
                                        type: 'cardbooking',    
                                        bookingid: this.bookingid
                                      } 
                        // Run ajax
                        this.$.ajax.generateRequest();

                    },

                    handleResponse: function(){
                        console.log(this.data);                         
                    },

                }); 

    </script>
```

Comment: I guess i could create the element with the constructor and append it in there but it just seems a bit messy doing that. Anyones thoughts?

Comment: Actually i cannot do that as i cannot pass the workerid in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [conditional template](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#conditional-templates) to check if data is there:

```
 <template if='{{data.workerid}}'>
    <user-display userid="{{data.workerid}}"></user-display>
 </template>
```

Comment: Thanks Goce so much for pointing me in the right direction. The code ended up being  
`<template is="dom-if" if="{{data.workerid}}">
<user-display userid="{{data.workerid}}"></user-display>
</template>`

because of use of polymer 1.0. Once data.workerid becomes available it renders. Amazing, thanks again so much

Answer (score 0):

Final code Polymer 1.0

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{data.workerid}}">
    <user-display userid="{{data.workerid}}"></user-display>
</template>
```